# Is LabVIEW one of the supported languages for protocol buffers for gRPC?

Tags: server, client, grpc, labview, protoc

I'm currently working on creating a LabVIEW server and LabVIEW client for gRPC.
I would like to know if LabVIEW is one of the supported languages for protocol buffers for gRPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LabVIEW is not currently supported for gRPC, for official information on supported languages refer to the [gRPC Languages](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/) page.

There have been attempts at implementation using either C++, .Net or Python integration but no official packages that I am aware of.

Full gRPC implementation in a language is a pretty complex process that must enable a language to build classes based on the configuration of a Protobuf definition file.

Comment: How to implement gRPC for LabVIEW by integrating .Net?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a working example of this code. I know it is possible as I have seen a colleagues working implementation but that source code has since been lost. 

The caveat for this is that a significant portion of the gRPC implementation is the custom generation of classes for handling various protobuf files. This is not something that is readily handled under LabVIEW without a _LOT_ of scripting development.

Comment: Sure then @Steve

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source repository where NI has been building tools to enable users to create a LabVIEW Server gRPC interface:  https://github.com/ni/grpc-labview

There is not currently a lot of client support for gRPC in LabVIEW.